# Adding a Show instance to RWH's RandomState example

Tags: monads, haskell

I have just typed in the RandomState example from real world haskell. It looks like this:

```
import System.Random
import Control.Monad.State

type RandomState a = State StdGen a

getRandom :: Random a => RandomState a
getRandom =
  get >>= \gen ->
  let (val, gen') = random gen in
  put gen' >>
  return val

getTwoRandoms :: Random a => RandomState (a, a)
getTwoRandoms = liftM2 (,) getRandom getRandom
```

It works, but the result doesn't get displayed. I get the error message:

```
No instance for (Show (RandomState (Int, Int)))
  arising from a use of `print' at <interactive>:1:0-38
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Show (RandomState (Int, Int)))
In a stmt of a 'do' expression: print it
```

I am having some trouble adding an instance for Show RandomState. Can anyone show me how this is done?

Thanks.

Comment: To diagnose this, we'll need the code you used to try to print. I'm guessing you forgot a runState?

Comment: I didn't write any extra code for printing, I simply ran: getTwoRandoms :: (RandomState (Int, Int))
but RandomState doesn't know how to display itself. Sounds like I did forget a runState.

Comment: Maybe you want the `runTwoRandoms` one section below instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of being explicit, as **jberryman** and the comments on the question imply: **Something of type `RandomState (a, a)` is a function, not a value.** To do anything with it, you want to **run it with an initial state**.

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
> fmap (runState getTwoRandoms) getStdGen
((809219598,1361755735),767966517 1872071452)
```

This is essentially what the `runTwoRandoms` function a bit further in RWH is doing.

Comment: I am going to have to read that chapter again. I really thought I was starting to get it.

Comment: @Kurt: Is it the "hidden" function that's tripping you up? It is kind of confusing that you can treat something of type `State s a` like a value of type `a` inside a `do` block, despite it actually being a function of type `s -> (a, s)`.  Walking through a reimplementation of `State` seems to help some people get a better feel for how and why it works--I did that in [one of my previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956518/1957379#1957379) and I've seen a blog post or two go through it as well.

Comment: @Kurt: The State monad is weird. Think about it this way: all the monadic machinery (`>>=`, `return`, etc.) is *composing* a big function in the `State` wrapper. You then *do* stuff with that monad/function by applying `runState` which just take that function out of the `State` wrapper (like `fst` pulls the first element of a tuple, they just gave `runState` a clever name to confuse you)

Answer (score 2):

Since `RandomState` is a synonym for `State` and there isn't an instance of `show` defined for `State`, you won't be able to show it.

You would also not be able to `derive show` because `State` is just a wrapper for a function and Haskell has no way to define a `show` for functions that would be useful:

```
Prelude> show (+)

<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (Show (a -> a -> a))
      arising from a use of `show' at <interactive>:1:0-7
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (a -> a -> a))
    In the expression: show (+)
    In the definition of `it': it = show (+)
```

EDIT: Forgot to add the other piece: GHCi is giving you that error because it uses `show` behind the scenes on the expressions you enter... REPL and all that.